# Actualizar en la ejecucion del controlador el nuevo rol asignado

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en `ASP.NET` con `EntityFramework` e `Identity`. Tengo varios roles creados con `IdentityRole` y el problema es que cuando a un usuario le asigno un nuevo rol en un controlador e intento redirigirle a otro controlador que necesita autorización de ese rol no coge el nuevo rol asignado. La solución que tengo ahora mismo es desconectar al usuario y que tenga que volver a hacer login pero me gustaría encontrar una solución sin que el usuario tenga que volver a entrar. Lo intenté con `UpdateSecurityStampAsync` pero no me funciona. Pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor.

Controlador que asigna el rol

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewRole(string Id, [Bind("Empresa, Cif")] NewEmpresaViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            user.Empresa = model.Empresa;
            user.Cif = model.Cif;
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Empresa");
            await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ha Habido un error, inténtelo más tarde.");
                user.Empresa = null;
                user.Cif = null;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                return View(model);
            }
            //return RedirectToAction("NewProduct","Products");

            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(NewProduct));


        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Si intento redireccionarle al controlador `NewProduct` no me coge la nueva asignación de rol y el usuario no tiene autorización para esa vista.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:**

Pongo la solución en vez de borrar por si alguien más se encuentra con el mismo problema. El problema tiene que ver con las cookies guardadas. Utilizando el método `RefreshSignInAsync` se soluciona. Para mi caso concreto:

```
await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
```